# How to make rgba in illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

i have a logo in .ai and the customer wants me to save it as a rgba. I normally only work with cmyk and rgb, so how do i make it rgba in illustrator? Is rgba only for websites?
Thanks for your time..:)

Comment: Hello Marlene, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. If you want to know more about the site, please see the [tour](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/tour) and the [help] or ping one of us in the [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Answer (score 1):

Illustrator is normally rgba the background is transparent, unless you tell the save routine to treat it as white. Its just emulating paper, if you want to see it as transparent then just ask illustrator to show the transparency grid (**View → Show Transparency Grid...**).

Comment: Thanks for your answer:) So i really save it as a rgba the same way as rgb?

Comment: @Marlene yes, thats right

Answer (score 0):

> Is rgba only for websites?

No.

RGBA is a file that is capable of having a transparency stored in the file itself. It is a normal RGB file + an alpha channel.

Yes, it could be a PNG file to be used as a logo on a website, but also can be a Photoshop's PSD with some mask, that can be used later in a composite, that can be printed directly on a digital printer or converted later to a CMYK format.

It does not matter how you want to use the transparency.

---

When you have a vector file (Illustrator, Corel Draw, Inkscape), any transparent or semi-transparent zone, either a zone without any solid shape or a shape with any kind of transparency can be exported to a raster image. But only some file formats hold this additional channel.

PNG, PSD, TIF, TGA are some common file formats.

---

The way Photoshop uses the concept, is a bit different. The original concept was that the file has this transparency so you can see thru it. Period.

But Photoshop uses it to hold "potential" transparency. A transparency that can be applied later, in this case, it is simply a latent channel that can be used or not.

---

> the customer wants me to save it as an RGBA

You do not "save" it as RGBA, you "export" it to a file that stores this transparency. But this export needs to take into account the resolution or file dimension. So you probably need additional information, for example, if you need a 500x500 png logo.